504 Gateway timeout API
I am encountering a 504 Gateway Timeout error when making API calls for a web scraping task on my deployed application. The same code works perfectly fine in my local environment without any timeout issues.
Below is the code where I am scrapping and getting 504 but its getting scraped
async function scrapeMyntra(url) {
    // Set up Chrome options
    const options = new chrome.Options();
    options.addArguments('--headless');
    options.addArguments('--no-sandbox');
    options.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage');
    options.addArguments('--disable-http2');
    options.addArguments('--disable-gpu');
    options.addArguments('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');

    // Initialize the WebDriver
    const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(options).build();

    try {

        await driver.get('https://proxyium.com/');
        try {
            const consentButton = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('.fc-button.fc-cta-consent.fc-primary-button')), 10000);
            await consentButton.click();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Consent button not found or could not be clicked. Proceeding...');
        }

        const searchInput = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('unique-form-control')), 10000);
        await searchInput.sendKeys(url);
        const submitButton = await driver.findElement(By.id('unique-btn-blue'));
        await submitButton.click();

        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('h1.pdp-title')), 10000);

        const getText = async (selector, defaultValue = '') => {
            try {
                const element = await driver.findElement(By.css(selector));
                return await element.getText();
            } catch (error) {
                return defaultValue;
            }
        };

        // Function to get background image URL from a CSS property
        const getImageUrl = async (selector, defaultValue = '') => {
            try {
                const element = await driver.findElement(By.css(selector));
                const style = await element.getAttribute('style');
                const urlMatch = style.match(/url\(["']?([^"']+)["']?\)/);
                return urlMatch ? urlMatch[1] : defaultValue;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error fetching image for selector "${selector}":`, error);
                return defaultValue;
            }
        };

        // Get product details
        const title = await getText('h1.pdp-title', '');
        const description = await getText('.pdp-product-description-content', '');
        const discount_price = await getText('.pdp-price strong', '');
        const originalPrice = await getText('.pdp-mrp s', '');
        const original_price = originalPrice.replace(/MRP\s*/, '').trim();

        let percentage_off = await getText('span.pdp-discount', '0%');
        percentage_off = percentage_off.replace('OFF', '').replace(/[()\s]/g, '').trim();

        const photo = await getImageUrl('.image-grid-image', '');

        // Construct the response object
        const responseObject = {
            title,
            original_price: original_price ? original_price : "₹0",
            discount_price: discount_price ? discount_price : "₹0",
            percentage_off: percentage_off ? percentage_off :"0%",
            photo,
            description: description ? description : title
        };

        return responseObject;

    } finally {
        await driver.quit(); // Close the browser
    }
}

